Multiple trims to a video using ffmpeg generating video with shorter duration than expected
I have an application that given a video it trims multiple parts of that video using ffmpeg. Each part is cropped, scaled and then concatenated to generate a single video.
To share an example, I have a video of 1 minute and 44 seconds of duration and 60 fps. My goal is to trim 3 parts of the video:

First one between seconds 0 to 44.666
Second one between seconds 44.666 to 74.349
Third one between seconds 74.349 to 103.985

The ffmpeg command I use to achieve that is the following one:
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i bg_720_1280.png -i error.mp4 -filter_complex "
[1:v]trim=0.0:44.666,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=405.0:720.0:437.5:0.0,scale=-2:1280.0[crop_1_0_v];
[1:a]atrim=0.0:44.666,volume=1.0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_1_0_a];
[0:v][crop_1_0_v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,44.666)':x=0.0:y=0.0[crop_1_0_v];
[1:v]trim=44.666:74.349,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=405.0:720.0:437.5:0.0,scale=-2:1280.0[crop_2_0_v];
[1:a]atrim=44.666:74.349,volume=1.0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_2_0_a];
[0:v][crop_2_0_v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,29.683)':x=0.0:y=0.0[crop_2_0_v];
[1:v]trim=74.349:103.985,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,crop=405.0:720.0:437.5:0.0,scale=-2:1280.0[crop_3_0_v];
[1:a]atrim=74.349:103.985,volume=1.0,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_3_0_a];
[0:v][crop_3_0_v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,29.636)':x=0.0:y=0.0[crop_3_0_v];
[crop_1_0_a][crop_2_0_a][crop_3_0_a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[a];
[crop_1_0_v][crop_2_0_v][crop_3_0_v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv];
[a]amix=1:duration=longest[outa]" -map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -sws_flags lanczos -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -preset superfast -r 60 test.mp4

Running this command it generates a video of 11 seconds of duration and I'm unable to understand it. What is wrong with the command? Also I'm open to recommendations of the ffmpeg command in case you find another way more efficient or performant.
I tried to isolate the error using this reduced command:
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -i error.mp4 -filter_complex "
[0:v]trim=0:45,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_1_0_v];
[0:v]trim=45:74,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_2_0_v];
[0:v]trim=74:104,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[crop_3_0_v];
[crop_1_0_v][crop_2_0_v][crop_3_0_v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[outv]" -map "[outv]" -vcodec libx264 -sws_flags lanczos -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 17 -preset superfast -r 60 test.mp4

But using this command I get a video of 1 minute and 24 seconds instead of 1 minute and 44 seconds.
I'm using the following FFMPEG version:
ffmpeg version 7.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
  libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
  libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
  libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
  libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
  libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100

But I got the same issue with static ffmpeg builds
The file bg_720_1280.png is just a transparent image of resolution 720x1280. I think I could achieve the same by using nullsrc filter with that resolution instead of using this background image.
